# How do I calculate a multiple factorial using num_bigint in Rust?

Tags: math, rust

I am trying to calculate a factorial of a factorial in Rust using the [Num-BigInt](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint) library. I've gotten to the point where I can calculate a factorial:

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::{One, Zero, FromPrimitive};

fn factorial(n: usize) -> BigUint {
    let mut f: BigUint = One::one();
    for i in 1..(n+1) {
        let bu: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_usize(i).unwrap();
        f = f * bu;
    }
    f
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Starting calculation...");
    println!("{}", factorial(5));
}
```

I want to do a double factorial, like:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    println!("Starting calculation...");
    println!("{}", factorial(factorial(5))); 
}
```

However, this throws the following error because the data types are different:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:16:30
   |
16 |     println!("{}", factorial(factorial(5)));
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected `usize`, found struct `BigUint`
```

How can I repeat this function using `BigUint` instead of `usize`?

Comment: Your function takes a `usize`. If you want it to take a `BigUint`, then the only thing stopping you is yourself. Just change the type signature

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The problem is that that BigUint doesn't allow manipulation like addition etc directly, unlike `usize`

Comment: While I'm not personally familiar with the library, a cursory glance at the source code shows the [requisite traits](https://github.com/rust-num/num-bigint/blob/master/src/biguint/addition.rs) implemented correctly.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. We can't tell what crates (and their versions), types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: Perhaps the problem is the range `1..(n+1)` when `n` is `BigUint`?  That could be rewritten, though.

Comment: If you wish to close your question, there should be a dedicated "close" link underneath the post itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you first want to use a `usize` and then a `BigUint` as your function parameter, while your parameter is set to be a `usize`.

To fix this you should make your `factorial` function [generic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html) and then only allow those types that make sense for your particular method.

I took your example and extended it to allow for all unsigned integer types:

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::{One, FromPrimitive, Unsigned};
use num::{Integer, NumCast, ToPrimitive};

fn factorial<N: Unsigned + Integer + ToPrimitive>(n: N) -> BigUint {
    let mut f: BigUint = One::one();
    let end: usize = NumCast::from(n).unwrap();
    for i in 1..(end + 1) {
        let bu: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_usize(i).unwrap();
        f = f * bu;
    }
    f
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Starting calculation...");
    println!("{}", factorial(factorial(5 as u32)));
}
```

This will however lead to not allowing `factorial(5)`, because `5` is treated as an `i32` by default, which can be signed. If you wish to allow for signed types and instead fail at runtime you can do something like that:

```rust
use num_bigint::BigUint;
use num_traits::{One, FromPrimitive};
use num::{Integer, NumCast, ToPrimitive};

fn factorial<N: Integer + ToPrimitive>(n: N) -> BigUint {
    let mut f: BigUint = One::one();
    let end: usize = NumCast::from(n).expect("Number too big or negative number used.");
    for i in 1..(end + 1) {
        let bu: BigUint = FromPrimitive::from_usize(i).unwrap();
        f = f * bu;
    }
    f
}

pub fn main() {
    println!("Starting calculation...");
    println!("{}", factorial(factorial(5)));
}
```